# How to run rest API in VBA taking parameter from 1 sheet and store response values in another sheet in columns?

Tags: excel, vba, rest

I have a situation where i need to run one API based on different parameters and need to store the response values in another sheet. parameter will be from one sheet.

refer the attached excel file for the data where in Repo Data sheet we have repositories and Result sheet we need values to be stored like this from API.

curl --location 'https://sonarcloud.io/api/measures/component?component=imonline_accountmanagement.webapi.reseller&metricKeys=bugs%2Cvulnerabilities%2Csecurity_hotspots%2Csecurity_hotspots_reviewed%2Ccode_smells%2Ccoverage%2Cduplicated_lines_density%2Cduplicated_blocks%2Cncloc%2Ctests%2Cuncovered_lines%2Csqale_rating%2Creliability_rating%2Csecurity_rating%2Csecurity_review_rating&branch=master' 
--header 'Authorization: Basic NGZhNmFkZDFhNmMyNDRkMjdlNjI0MDVjYTQ3YWJmNjhmNzdiYjI0Njo='

Eg: Response

```
{
"component": {
"id": "AX1rRbipdJtPV1ET12n1",
"key": "imonline_accountmanagement.webapi.reseller",
"name": "AccountManagement.WebApi.Reseller",
"qualifier": "TRK",
"measures": [
{
"metric": "coverage",
"value": "43.8",
"bestValue": false
},
{
"metric": "reliability_rating",
"value": "1.0",
"bestValue": true
},
{
"metric": "code_smells",
"value": "126",
"bestValue": false
},
{
"metric": "duplicated_lines_density",
"value": "4.6",
"bestValue": false
},
{
"metric": "security_rating",
"value": "1.0",
"bestValue": true
},
{
"metric": "security_hotspots_reviewed",
"value": "0.0",
"bestValue": false
},
{
"metric": "security_hotspots",
"value": "141",
"bestValue": false
},
{
"metric": "security_review_rating",
"value": "5.0",
"bestValue": false
},
{
"metric": "sqale_rating",
"value": "1.0",
"bestValue": true
},
{
"metric": "bugs",
"value": "0",
"bestValue": true
},
{
"metric": "tests",
"value": "41"
},
{
"metric": "uncovered_lines",
"value": "444",
"bestValue": false
},
{
"metric": "duplicated_blocks",
"value": "13",
"bestValue": false
},
{
"metric": "ncloc",
"value": "4361"
},
{
"metric": "vulnerabilities",
"value": "0",
"best Value": true
}
]
}
}
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having when trying to get this set up?